# How to find the current position of a point within the grid after changing the grid shape?

Tags: algorithm, math

**i want to find position of a point within grid after changing the grid shape**

For Example:
In the below image i have a grid with dimensions (10,10),(20,10),(10,20),(20,20).
There is **point (x) within grid** and that  **point position is (17,13)**

[image]

Now i change the dimension of the grid so grid shape gets changed

 
Previous grid shape get changed like this 
[image]

After changing the shape of the grid

Grid dimensions are (8,8),(18,12),(12,18),(22,19)

**Now what will be the position of the point (x)?**

 *Can anyone explain the way to find the **solution or 
algorithm** to find the current position of point..*
Thanks in advance..

Comment: School assignment ? What have you tried to approach this problem ?

Comment: And how shape of the grid is changed? What data describe that changes?

Comment: The way to find a solution or algorithm is to go to Wikipedia and look at articles on *bilinear interpolation*, *bicubic inerpolation* and related topics.

Comment: The last comment should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

A basic idea:

- Draw a line from one corner through the point. Record the point in the side it goes through.
- Do the same for a neighbouring corner.
- For the transformed square, draw lines between the same corners and where their lines went through the sides.
- Where the lines cross should be where the point belongs.

**A few notes:**

As per its definition, a line extends infinitely.

You need to use neighbouring corners (as mentioned). If you use opposing corners, and the point is on the line between the corners, you won't be able to narrow it down beyond that line. Actually if the point can be on one of the sides, using neighbouring corners will give the same problem. In this case you'll need 3 corners.

This works because 2 lines can only + must have 1 crossing point, unless they are parallel (which can only happen in the above scenario - 2 lines containing the same point must be equal or non-parallel). If we add another corner, due to the square-shape, it can't be parallel to the other 2 lines.

Another special case pops up if 3 corners can end up on the same line. In this case, you'll need to use all 4 corners. But if all 4 corners can end up on the same line, this won't work, but in this case the resulting shape will just be a line segment.

You can also use distances, just remember to use ratio's instead of actual distances due to shape distortion.

Comment: Does this give a unique result or does it make a difference as to which corners you use? By my back of the envelope calculation it does. So even if this gives a good answer you need to find a method of making it consistent too.